# dtsConfig settings not applied when calling SSIS package from ASP.NET page?

Tags: asp.net, ssis

I have an SSIS package with a .dtsConfig file. When I run the .dtsx package using the 'Execute Package Utility' then settings from the dtsConfig file get applied fine.

However, when I try and run the SSIS package from an ASP.NET page the settings in the dtsConfig file are not applied.

Anyone know why this may be?

Many thanks!

Anthony

Comment: How do you run this from ASP.NET? How do you ensure that you are telling the API to look for the dtsConfig file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Faiz - I didn't realise you needed to tell the package from the codebehind the location and filename of the dtsConfig settings. I thought that because I told the package what the filename of the config file was when I was creating it that that would be sufficient.

I needed to add the following lines:

```
        myPackage.EnableConfigurations = True
        myPackage.ImportConfigurationFile(packageConfigPath)
```